# how to transpose a 5x5 matrix using mapreduce

Tags: mapreduce

I have tried that mapper is dividing the matrix into `2x2` and giving it to reducer. The reducer perform transpose for each `2x2` matrix. But while dividing odd order matrix into `2x2` leaving `1x1` matrix at the end. So how to write a map and reduce function to overcome this problem. Please send me a solution.

Comment: This seems like an easy problem to solve without MapReduce.  Is there a particular reason why you want to force it into MR?

Comment: Yes I want to know whether time complexity will be redced or not by using MapReduce

Comment: I don't know of any application where MapReduce reduces the computational complexity.  The advantage of MR is that you can use many processors and work on files too large to fit on a single disk.  For small things (like a 5x5 matrix) MR will almost certainly kill your performance.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the matrix is in csv delimited for columns and new line for rows. You can read line by line in map task
For each line, do a split based on comma and get token for each column.
Now you would need a custom value object for reducer(inherit from writable), which would store the line_number & value at specific column.

The map task would emit, the key as column number at which column value is read and value would be the custom value object defined above.

You would need a secondary sort/comparator which would sort based on custom value object's line_number filed so that when the order can be maintained when values would be iterated at reducer end.

At reducer, just read the keys sorted based on line number, get the iterator for each key and create a csv string and write to output file.